# how to add libc++.dylib to a Xcode project created by trigger.io forge

Tags: trigger.io

How to add libc++.dylib to a Xcode project created by trigger.io forge

I add the libc++.dylib file to the Xcode project "ForgeInspector", but it will removed when i update from website.

How can i add the libc++.dylib to the project file made by trigger.io?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a build step in `module/ios/build_steps.json`. See https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/native_build_steps.html

For `libc++.dylib` the file should contain the following:

```
[
    { "do": { "add_ios_system_framework": "libc++.dylib" } }
]
```